# PHP Shell_Exec not working?

Tags: php, c, linux

I have the following code:

```
$output = shell_exec("./Program $var1 $var2");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

It doesn't work but

```
$output = shell_exec("ls");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

does work.

```
$output = shell_exec("top");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

also doesn't work for example. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is most certainly a permissions issue.  Make sure that the file you're trying to execute with the ./ command from your script has +x perms.  Here's a previous thread about giving files executable permissions: [Creating executable files in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817060/creating-executable-files-in-linux).

If the file already has +x rights, it could be a permissions issue with your script running the commands.  Either way, if you can run ls but not ./ and top, has to be permissions.

Edit: The link I gave, I realize has a lot of info about Perl and bash scripts.  The important part is that the command to make a file executable is

```
chmod +x ProgramName
```

Comment: Hm.  When you say it doesn't work, can you include in your question what error it gives?  Or does it just print an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the content of $var1 and $var2 you may need to do an `escapeshellarg` call around it.

```
 $output = shell_exec("./Program ".escapeshellarg($var1)." ".escapeshellarg($var2));
```

even if it doesn't work it might be a good idea.  Also confirm that your Path is correct. Maybe with a `file_exits('./Program');` check