# .bash_profile aliases: command not found

Tags: macos, alias, bash

I cannot get my .bash_profile aliases to work on my Mac OSX Terminal. I created a .bash_profile file in my ~/ directory, then wrote two lines:

```
echo bash profile has loaded

alias prof=“open ~/.bash_profile”
```

I saved and entered in Terminal command:

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Terminal displayed:

```
bash profile has loaded

-bash: alias: /Users/kennethlarose/.bash_profile”: not found
```

I've been reading up on alias profiles, and I believe my syntax is valid. I know the profile is sourcing because it displays the echo, but Terminal will show the same 'not found' message no matter what command I save in the alias. Does anybody know what else I can try?

Comment: I just got this same error but it seems to have been because the command I wanted to alias was too long. When I tried the same format with a much shorter command it worked fine. So if you're trying to fun a very long command (not this case but a head's up for other readers), you should drop the command in a file and make the file executable like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817060/creating-executable-files-in-linux

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Let's ask shellcheck!

```
In .bash_profile line 2:
alias prof=“open ~/.bash_profile”
           ^-- SC1015: This is a unicode double quote. Delete and retype it.
```

There's your problem. OS X has turned your double quotes into fancy slanted quotes that bash doesn't recognize. If you're programming, you may want to [disable "smart quotes"](http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks).

Comment: Gee! That link helped me resolve the automatic spell check feature that was bugging the crap out of me. +1 for that.

Comment: Genius answer, why hasn't this been marked up to over 1000 already? Cheers

Comment: Thank you for this! I was racking my brain trying to figure out why a dead-simple alias wouldn't work properly.