# Why is my terminal alias failing

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm reading this: 
http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_aliases_commands

I wrote in my bash profile:
alias workspace = 'cd Documents/workspace'

however I get the following:

```
-bash: alias: workspace: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: cd Documents/workspace: not found
```

when I source the file. What's going on?

I searched on SO and found: [.bash_profile aliases: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319631/bash-profile-aliases-command-not-found) but I'm not using double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider removing the spaces around the = sign.

For reference:  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins

This is not on mac, but still bash:

```
$ cat with-spaces.sh
alias workspace = 'cd Documents/workspace'
$ . with-spaces.sh
./with-spaces.sh: line 1: alias: workspace: not found
./with-spaces.sh: line 1: alias: =: not found
./with-spaces.sh: line 1: alias: cd Documents/workspace: not found
$ # checking result...
$ alias workspace
bash: alias: workspace: not found

$ cat without-spaces.sh
alias workspace='cd Documents/workspace'
$ . without-spaces.sh
$ # checking result...
$ alias workspace
alias workspace='cd Documents/workspace'
```